# How to turn the value into true of an if condition in java NetBeans?

Tags: java, mysql, authentication, jbutton, netbeans-8

I have an else if part coded inside the action perform method of a jButton to check whether the given E_ID's U_LEVEL is "Admin" or "User".Below is the code.

```
if (E_ID.getText().trim().length() == 0 | PWD.getPassword() == null) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username or Password cannot be blank", "Error", 0);
    } else {
            try {
            ResultSet rs = new DBG1().getData("select * from USER where E_ID = '" +E_ID.getText() + "'");
            Vector v = new Vector();

            if (rs.next()) {
                v.add(rs.getString(1));
            }
            if (v.isEmpty()) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Username or Password", "Error", 0);
                E_ID.setText("");
                PWD.setText("");
                E_ID.grabFocus();

            } else {
                ResultSet rs1 = new DBG1().getData("select * from USER where E_ID ='" + E_ID.getText() + "'");
                while (rs1.next()) {
                    String type = (rs1.getString(2));                        

                    if (E_ID.getText().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(rs1.getString("E_ID")) && PWD.getText().equals(rs1.getString("PWD"))&& type.equals("Admin")) {// 
                      //  this.dispose();
                       new Home_Page(E_ID.getText()).setVisible(true);

                    } else if (E_ID.getText().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(rs1.getString("E_ID")) && PWD.getText().equals(rs1.getString("PWD")) && type.equals("User")) {
                        this.dispose();
                       new Home_Page(E_ID.getText()).setVisible(true);

                    } 
                    else {

                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Username or Password", "Error", 0);
                        E_ID.setText("");
                        PWD.setText("");
                        E_ID.grabFocus();
                    }
                }
                this.dispose();
              }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

In above code there is an else-if. in that if part,

```
E_ID.getText().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(rs1.getString("E_ID"))
```

part and

```
 PWD.getText().equals(rs1.getString("PWD"))
```

part retrieve a true value but

```
type.equals("Admin")
```

part retrieves a false value even though the MYSQL database "final_post" contains a table called USER in which there is a column called U_LEVEL under which I have saved the values "Admin"  and "User".

```
mysql> select * from USER;
+-------+-------+-----+------+
| E_ID  | type  | PWD | CPWD |
+-------+-------+-----+------+
| E/14  | Admin | qwe | qwe  |
| SEC/1 | User  | qw  | qw   |
+-------+-------+-----+------+
2 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

I need to turn the value of

```
 type.equals("Admin")
```

into true.Where should I make the amendments?Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the value of type?

Comment: type is a String String type = (rs1.getString(3));

Comment: I am not so sure but I think the value inside the brackets should be 2.

Comment: i don't care about the type. what is the value? you want to compare the value with "Admin" and obviously they are not equal, so what is the value of `type`

Comment: value of type = "Admin"

Comment: `Admin` or `Admin `? maybe other values are incorrect?

Comment: I found what was wrong. :) String type=(rs1.getString(3)); should have String type=(rs1.getString(2));  That means the U_LEVEL column of the table. silly me

Answer (score 0):

I found where I should amend.
In here the variable type refers to the column PWD of the table USER.
But I have compared it with the String "Admin".
That is why it had retrieved false value.
Once I corrected the column index the else if worked correctly. :)
String type = (rs1.getString(3));  this should have String type = (rs1.getString(2)); 
That's all. :)